# Jquery & Ajax - Return False is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have ajax call inside in another ajax call. The return false in my success function of the second ajax call is not working and the form is always submit.

Basically I calculate the sum of my database column records (percent_shares) and the user when he try to insert new record, the ajax is check if the total is greater than 100. When the user is save value in the input and the total of the records is greater than 100 is showing my error message but the form is submitted. I try to stop the submit but is not working.

```
$('#officer_entity_helper_category').on('change', function() {
   var entity_helper_category = $(this).val();

   $("#shareholder_name_id").on('change', function(e){
       contactID = e.target.value;
       contacts_user_function();
   });
}); 

function contacts_user_function() { 
        $.ajax({
            url:'/companies/ajax/contactsDetails',
            method: 'post',
            data: {id: contactID},
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(response){                
                var len = response.length;
                $('#fname').text('');
                if(len > 0){
                    // Read values
                    var fname = response[0].fname;
            
                    $('#fname').text(fname);

                    $( ".btn-primary" ).click(function(e) {
                        totalPercent();
                    });                  
                }
            }
        });
}

function totalPercent() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'/companies/ajax/totalPercentShares',
            method: 'post',
            data: {company_id: $("#company_id").data('id'),
            contact_id: contactID                    
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: 'false',
            success: function(data){
                var x = data;
                var percent_share = parseFloat($("#percent_shares").val());                
                var percent_share_sum = parseFloat(x);                
                var total = (percent_share) + (percent_share_sum);

                if (total > 100) {
                    $(".errorTxt").html("Your total of percent shares should be 100.");
                    return  false;
                } else {
                    $(".errorTxt").html("");
                    return true;
                }    
            }          
        });   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the `click` method needs to return `true` or `false`, but in this case you're not returning the value of `totalPercent` - so even though you return values in the `$.ajax` call, it doesn't have any effect. given how your code is structured, you could consider using a callback, or you could restructure it to use `async` and `await`

something like this would probably work..

```js
$('#someElement').on('click', async () => {
    return new Promise((res,rej) => {
        try {
            totalPercent(result => {
                res(result);
            });
        catch ( err ) {
            rej(err);
        }
    });
});

// add callback to totalPercent
function totalPercent(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'/companies/ajax/totalPercentShares',
            method: 'post',
            data: {company_id: $("#company_id").data('id'),
            contact_id: contactID                    
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: 'false',
            success: function(data){
                var x = data;
                var percent_share = parseFloat($("#percent_shares").val());                
                var percent_share_sum = parseFloat(x);                
                var total = (percent_share) + (percent_share_sum);

                if (total > 100) {
                    $(".errorTxt").html("Your total of percent shares should be 100.");
                    return callback(false);
                } else {
                    $(".errorTxt").html("");
                    return callback(true);
                }    
            }          
        });   
    }
```

Comment: i tried it but still not working

Comment: it's possible you need something like `e.preventDefault()` depending on your browser, alternatively if you want to post a working (or mostly working) example to jsfiddle i can probably take a look at it for you :)